# Positioning of JButton in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, button, awt, frame

This is very basic code but i just need some help to understand..

i have a button and i want to place it on the EAST side of the Panel.. any suggestions..

```
    public class ButtonText { 
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Frame frame=new Frame("Button Frame");
            Button button = new Button("Submit"); 
            frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            frame.add(button, BorderLayout.EAST);
            frame.setSize(200,100);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
            {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
```

which looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHX4Y.jpg

any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: The Problem is that you tell your frame to use a FlowLayout, but expect it to understand BorderLayout Parameters. Just set the layout from your frame to frame.setLayout( new BorderLayout() ); and it should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To lay your user interface out with a border layout manager, you need to set your frame's layout to an instance of BorderLayout.  A default FlowLayout sets components out from left to right and onto next lines if necessary.

```
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.add(button, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Comment: could this also work with a box layout? or totally different? re. positioning?

Comment: It *could* but not so simply; you could add a horizontal glue before adding the component to stick it to the right side rather than the left.  Layout managers all handle the second method arguments differently; `BorderLayout.EAST` won't necessary stick an object on the right side in a FlowLayout, BoxLayout, or any other layout than it was intended for.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but just another question - i need to place this Jbutton on the end of two JTextFields but it just places it under the one JTextField.. if you understand? any suggestions?  thanks

Comment: Use multiple JPanels and add them to each other.  *Or* use a GUI layout designer to generate the code for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Layout that positions the elements in the frame. Take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). You are using a [FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html), but you need to understand each layout and the rules positioning elements.

Answer (score 0):

`FlowLayout` cant use `BorderLayout` constraints...

Try using `BorderLayout`instead of `FlowLayout` and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Flowlayout doesn't let you do that**, you should set the

```
     frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     frame.add(button, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

or

```
     frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     frame.add(button, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
```

to make it work,

The **Flowlayout** only positions things like a horizontal stack.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try something like this

```
Frame frame=new Frame("Button Frame");

Button button = new Button("Submit"); 

HorizontalPanel hp = new HorizontalPanel();
hp.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_RIGHT);
hp.setWidth(200);
hp.add(button);

frame.add(hp);
frame.setSize(200,100);
frame.setVisible(true);
```